# "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am getting this error although VS2015RC is looking for wrong relative path which is not even used in my class library project.

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Is it related to .pdb or some temporary files.

Comment: Did you check the architectural compatibility between your project and the libs you are using. For ex: If you build your project in 64bit, you nee to use lib in 64bit...

Comment: its not running even in debug mode and all my libraries are compatible.... Its a runtime error